# Large archival storage laypout

Tags: debian, raid, zfs, nas

I am playing with a though of buying into a large redundant storage for all the family data like old photos, causal backups and such.

My primary question here is how to layout it so it is safe, accessible, and works with the zoo of home devices. The basic idea was to grab a 2- or 4-port NAS, pull some ZFS on it and forget the issue. All the access happens per SMB/SFTP/whatever, and the ZFS handles redundancy on the bunch of disks. If a disk fries I will still be able to read it on a normal machine, because it's not locked-in property RAID.

But what happens if the NAS is struck by a lightning? Or, more realistically, I have lost most of my data not because of an apparent hardware issue, but because the file system fried. Hello, HFS+, my old friend...

I have thought of getting *two* NASes, one, like 2-bay for everyday issues, for daily backups of normal machines, and having it as a media hub is a plus. And a second NAS with all the ZFS deduplication perks for backuping the decivise parts of the first NAS. But that is slowly getting out of my comfortable price range.

Say, 2-bay with larger drives with a part of both drives as RAID-0 (or ZFS counterpart) for daily and *ok to break* things. And a part as RAID-1 (or better ZFS on JBOD) for backuping the sensible things. But the backup part should obviously be larger than the scratch part. So, taking the standard 4 TB drives and partitioning even in 25:75, I would bet 2 TB scratch and 3 TB backup. Isn't it easier and cheaper just to buy a few external 2-3 TB drives and suffer?

Causal backups of all Macs in the house run as of now with their Time Machine, so I would also need to trick a Mac into thinking that the NAS is an Ok destination for a network backup. But that's another story and I am content with creating a sparse disk image for the sake of backup.

My question seems like I do not really know what I want. I would like to hear:

- Experience reports with NAS and data security. (I will be scanning all the family photos from *years* ago, and do not want to do this twice, especially as the physical original source decays.)
- File system choices. ZFS vs. ext4 vs. TIMBZJVBWEJVKSAFNGSAHFSTFS vs. what the NAS supports vs. what I can beat a Mac into reading with Fuse. Please no NTFS, HFS+, plain UFS, and exFAT unless you can really convince me.
- Configuration suggestions. On an unlimited budget I would go for, like 4- and 8-bay NAS, just because. What is an overkill and what is not. Does having *two* NASes make any sense?
- A smart NAS or a low-key PC with a lot of hard drives / a "dumb" NAS?
- I want a had-bad-sex-when-configuring-it once, runs-like-a-charm-ever-since setup. I might be lazy and give off Mac vibes, but I have worked years as a low-tier Linux admin in my earlier years. So, if I need to pull my own OS on that thing, that would probably be a Debian.

Comment: You should consider asking on Reddit, on the [DataHoarder](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/) subredit.  It's a surprisingly knowledgeable and helpful community by today's standards.

Answer (score 2):

There is not trickery to be done configuring backups for Macs, Time machine does accept remote drives as destination for backups.

ZFS in a RAID configuration is the way to go.

> What is ZFS?   ZFS is an enterprise-ready open source file system,
>   RAID controller, and volume manager with unprecedented flexibility and
>   an uncompromising commitment to data integrity. It eliminates most, if
>   not all of the shortcomings found in legacy file systems and hardware
>   RAID devices. Once you go ZFS, you will never want to go back.

see also FreeNAS http://www.freenas.org for a free implementation of a NAS "appliance software" with a management web interface, based in FreeBSD+ZFS.

> FreeNAS is an operating system that can be installed on virtually any
>   hardware platform to share data over a network. FreeNAS is the
>   simplest way to create a centralized and easily accessible place for
>   your data. Use FreeNAS with ZFS to protect, store, backup, all of your
>   data. FreeNAS is used everywhere, for the home, small business, and
>   the enterprise.

About the hardware: actually also for ZFS you *do not want* hardware RAID cards, as this hides the actual hard disk geometry from ZFS. Your best bet is using PCs/servers that support multiple *fast* hard disks.

ZFS also needs memory depending on the size of disks. Be prepared for such a rig to have *at least* 8GB of RAM.